# What is the difference between setUp() and setUpClass() in Python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

What is the difference between `setUp()` and `setUpClass()` in the Python `unittest` framework? Why would setup be handled in one method over the other?

I want to understand what part of setup is done in the `setUp()` and `setUpClass()` functions, as well as with `tearDown()` and `tearDownClass()`.

Answer (score 237):

The difference manifests itself when you have more than one test method in your class. `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` are run once for the whole class; `setUp` and `tearDown` are run before and after each test method.

For example:

```
class Example(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("setUpClass")

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp")

    def test1(self):
        print("test1")

    def test2(self):
        print("test2")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("tearDown")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("tearDownClass")
```

When you run this test, it prints:

```
setUpClass
setUp
test1
tearDown
.setUp
test2
tearDown
.tearDownClass
```

(The dots (`.`) are `unittest`'s default output when a test passes.) Observe that `setUp` and `tearDown` appear before and after `test1` *and* `test2`, whereas `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` appear only once, at the beginning and end of the whole test case.

Comment: Shouldn't the order be this ? : 
setUpClass
setUp
test1
tearDown
.setUp
test2
.tearDown
tearDownClass

Comment: Notice the "." in front of tearDown and the absence of "." in front of tearDownClass

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn’t spot that. No, `unittest` doesn’t consider a test to have passed until its `tearDown` has completed without incident.

Comment: So each of the methods test1 and test2 should have their own set of setUp & tearDown, right? In your answer, test1 doesn't have any tearDown method and thus it should've printed the default output(with the . ). Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: The output in the answer is correct. I pasted it directly from unittest’s output. `setUp` and `tearDown` are each run once for every `test` method (so twice in total in this example) but `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` are run just once each.

Answer (score 34):

## What is the difference between `setUp()` and `setUpClass()` in the Python `unittest` framework?

The main difference (as noted in the answer by Benjamin Hodgson) is that `setUpClass` is called only once and that is before all the tests, while `setUp` is called immediately before each and every test. (NB: The same applies to the equivalent methods in other xUnit test frameworks, not just Python's `unittest`.)

From the `unittest` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html):

> `setUpClass()`
>
> A class method called before tests in an individual class are run. setUpClass is called with the class as the only argument and must be decorated as a classmethod():

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    ...
```

and:

> `setUp()`
>
> Method called to prepare the test fixture. This is called immediately before calling the test method; other than AssertionError or SkipTest, any exception raised by this method will be considered an error rather than a test failure. The default implementation does nothing.

## Why would setup be handled in one method over the other?

This part of the question has not been answered yet. As per my comment in response to the answer by Gearon, the `setUp` method is meant for elements of the fixture that are common to all tests (to avoid duplicating that code in each test). I find this is often useful as removing duplication (usually) improves readability and reduces the maintenance burden.

The `setUpClass` method is for expensive elements that you would rather only have to do once, such as opening a database connection, opening a temporary file on the filesystem, loading a shared library for testing, etc. Doing such things before each test would slow down the test suite too much, so we just do it once before all the tests. This is a slight degradation in the independence of the tests but a necessary optimization in some situations. Arguably, one should not be doing such things in unit tests as it is usually possible to mock the database / filesystem / library / whatever without using the real thing. As such, I find that `setUpClass` is rarely needed. However, it is useful when testing the above examples (or similar) becomes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `setUp()` and `setUpClass()` methods in the Python unittest framework are used to set up the test environment before running the tests. The main difference between the two methods is that:

| Method | When is it called? | What is it used for? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `setUp()` | Before each test method is run | Setting up the test environment for each individual test method |
| `setUpClass()` | Once, before all the tests in the class are run | Setting up the test environment for the entire class |

Here are some examples of when you might want to use `setUpClass()` instead of `setUp()`:

1. If you need to create a database connection or a web driver that will be used by all the tests in the class.
2. If you need to load some initial data into the database.
3. If you need to set some global configuration options.

In general, you should use `setUpClass()` for tasks that need to be done only once, before all the tests in the class are run. You should use `setUp()` for tasks that need to be done before each individual test method is run.

The `tearDown()` and `tearDownClass()` methods are used to tear down the test environment after the tests have been run. The `tearDown()` method is called after each test method is run, and the `tearDownClass()` method is called after all the tests in the class have been run. These methods are used to clean up any resources that were used by the tests, such as database connections or web drivers, and to reset the test environment to its initial state.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned above, setup() and teardown() will run after and before each test. however SetupClass() and TearDownClass() will run only once for the whole class.