# Pytest setup/teardown hooks for session

Tags: python, unit-testing, hook, pytest

`Pytest` [has](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html) `setup and teardowns` hooks for `module, class, method`.

I want to create my custom test environment in setup (before start of test session) and cleanup after all tests will be finished.
In other words, how can I use hooks like `setup_session and teardown_session`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667610/difference-between-setupclass-and-setup-in-python-unittest

Comment: @AriGold. Actually I do not use any unittest class. I am writing test functions that using pytest fixtures. I see the example of setup_class/teardown_class usage in your link. But I am looking for something like  setup_session/teardown_session.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

These hooks work well for me:

```
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    # setup_stuff

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    # teardown_stuff
```

But actually next fixture with session scope looks much prettier:

```
@fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def my_fixture():
    # setup_stuff
    yield
    # teardown_stuff
```

Comment: That is the approach I was using (a session-scoped auto-use fixture). However, in pytest version `4.0` [they removed yield tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#yield-tests) and this appears to no longer work. Any alternatives that you know of?

Comment: @campellcl You missunderstood the difference between yield tests and yield fixtures as I can see. I just tested my code with pytest==4.0.0 and it worked like a charm). So you should use asserts inside tests instead of yeild-tests.

Comment: Do we have an option to make this work when we run test in parrallel. i see the same code keep on running for all tests

Comment: @Gauravkhurana You can try to create some lock mechanism (e.g. file) in setup, remove while teardown and skip initialization if it already existing.

Comment: Just a side note: using `pytest_sessionstart` will invoke the code **before** the collection, while the fixture version will be called after