# Unittest setUpClass method is not getting called

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-appium

I am trying to run my tests in parallel mode using ThreadPoolExecutor, here is my Runner class

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    if (options == 'by_method'):
        for object in name:
            for method in dir(object):
                if (method.startswith('test')):
                    suite.addTest(object(method))

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=devicesList.__len__()) as executor:
        list_of_suites = list(suite)
        for test in range(len(list_of_suites)):
            test_name = str(list_of_suites[test])
            try:
                executor.submit(unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run, list_of_suites[test])
            except:
                pass
```

And this is my test class

```
import unittest
class Runner(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        print("setup method")

    def test_deeplinks(self):
        print("test1")

    def test(self):
        print("test2");

    def test4(self):
        print("test 4")

    def test5(self):
        print("test5");

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        print("tear down ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # runner = Runner.Runner()
    # runner.parallel_execution(Runner, TestDeeplinks)
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Runner)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run
```

but my setupClass method is not getting called can anyone please tell what i'm doing here

Comment: But i want that this method should be called after all tests got executed

Comment: Your code is badly formatted. Please [edit] the question to fix the formatting. Also, please create a minimal example, rather than a maximal one. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @zvone Please check now

Comment: What is the output you get? If you remove the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Yes if umi run this without threadpoolexecutor it is working fine but i wanted to run this parallely

Comment: @zvone Anything wrong here?

Comment: found 1 thing when i add suite in the run method i.e. run(suite) then the classMethod is executed but in that cases test cases does not execute parallely, but when i remove suite from run method then test cases executed in parallel but classMethod fails to execute @zvone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `setUp()` instead of `setUpClass()`

`setUpClass()` only runs once per whole class

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23670844/6243764